# Hidden Rows in Bootstrap have a height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sure this has a simple answer but can't get my head around it.

I have bootstrap table that has hidden rows that display on click of the row that it's hidden behind. However, the hidden rows show up and I can't get them to disappear when they're not selected.

Trying to get rid of the highlighted space between rows as per this pic:
[image]

```
<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>GuideWire</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#info_1'>
        <td>Good</td>
        <td>FooBar</td>
        <td>Something else</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='8' class='hidden-row'>
          <div class='collapse' id='info_1'>
            <table class="table table-condensed table-sm small">
              <thead>
                <th>ABC</th>
                <th>DEF</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>S1</td>
                  <td>Blah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>S1</td>
                  <td>Blah</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#info_2'>
        <td>Good 2</td>
        <td>FooBar 2</td>
        <td>Something else 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='8' class='hidden-row'>
          <div class='collapse' id='info_2'>
            <table class="table table-condensed table-sm small">
              <thead>
                <th>ABC</th>
                <th>DEF</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>S1</td>
                  <td>Blah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>S1</td>
                  <td>Blah</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

If you know how to get .table-striped to ignore hidden rows too, that'd be great.

Comment: Link to jsfiddle as SO Editor wouldn't allow it on main question: https://jsfiddle.net/gnuchu/vf2k12kf/

Comment: Did you read the reason why it wouldn't let you add the link to fiddle.  Don't ignore the rules

Comment: @gnuchu -- please add the code in the question

Comment: @Pete: I did. Tried adding code but the error wouldn't go away until I removed it and the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the top & bottom padding. You can reset it with..

```
.table>tbody .hidden-row {
   padding: 0 8px;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Ev7XStMM0f

This way it's only adjusting the `hidden-row`, and not overriding the Bootstrap table defaults. Also, you probably want to keep the left/right padding so the columns in the hidden-row align properly.

Answer (score 1):

Its the padding which is giving it the space. 
This should work

```
.table>tbody>tr>td.hidden-row, .table>tbody>tr>th.hidden-row, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td.hidden-row, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th.hidden-row, .table>thead>tr>td.hidden-row, 
.table>thead>tr>th.hidden-row {
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the css properties

```
.table.table-hover {
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below code and let me know if it works for you

**CSS**

.inner-table-data
 {
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }

**HTML**



<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>GuideWire</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#info_1'>
                <td class="col-sm-4">Good</td>
                <td class="col-sm-4">FooBar</td>
                <td class="col-sm-4">Something else</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='1' class='collapse' id='info_1'>
                    <div>
                        <table class="table table-striped inner-table-data">
                            <thead>
                            <th>ABC</th>
                            <th>DEF</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>S1</td>
                                    <td>Blah</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>S1</td>
                                    <td>Blah</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#info_2'>
                <td class="col-sm-4">Good 2</td>
                <td class="col-sm-4">FooBar 2</td>
                <td class="col-sm-4">Something else 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='1' class='collapse' id='info_2'>
                    <div>
                        <table class="table table-striped inner-table-data">
                            <thead>
                            <th>ABC</th>
                            <th>DEF</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>S1</td>
                                    <td>Blah</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>S1</td>
                                    <td>Blah</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```